# Kill Process started by IO.popen automatically if parent ruby script is killed

Tags: ruby, io, pipe, popen

I'm trying to run ffmpeg from ruby script in windows.

```
def execute_ffmpeg(command)
  IO.popen(command){|io|
    io.each{|line|
      # Show Progress
    }
  }
end
command_ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -vb 1000k -ab 96k output.mp4 2>&1"
execute_ffmpeg(command_ffmpeg)
```

It works fine, if I wait until encoding finishes.
But if I terminate ruby script, the process of ffmpeg remains background.

How can I kill the ffmpeg process when parent ruby process is terminated?

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Have the child process share a pipe with the parent process. Have a thread in the child process call IO.select on it. If the pipe closes you know the parent process died. See https://github.com/vaneyckt/Adeona/blob/master/lib/adeona.rb for implementation.

edit: just noticed you're on Windows 7. Not sure if my approach works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As you mention because of fork I could not run the code in windows. and I read your code and reference manual again and again. But I could not rewrite it. I'll check it again after I learn about IO basics.